# Не работает !cat

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Пишу в jupyter:

```
file_obj = open("file_to_write_in.txt", 'w')
string = 'строка для записи в файл\n'
file_obj.write(string)
file_obj.close()
!cat file_to_write_in.txt
```

Получаю вывод:
"cat" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.

Comment: Проблема с кодировкой. Текст ошибки: `"cat" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. ` Возможно, неправильная установка jupyter.

Comment: Или если используете Windows - то аналог команды `cat` в ней -  `type`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.